# Is there a way to send multiple transactions to counterparty without looping

Tags: corda

Is there a way to send multiple transactions to a counterparty without using a loop in the flow? Sending one tx a time in a loop impacts the performance significantly since `Suspendable` behaviour doesn't work well with large volumn of txes.

At some point in time, `T`, an initiator may be interested in sending N numbers of transactions to a regulator/counterparty. But the current `SendTransactionsFlow` only send one tx at a time. And on the other side, it `ReceiveTransactionFlow` to record one by one.

My current code

```
relevantTxes.forEach{
       subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, signedTx))
}
```

Is there a way to do something along the line of

`subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(session, relevantTxes))`

Answer (score 0):

You can send the list of transactions without invoking a subflow by using `send` and `receive`.

On the sender's side:

```
val session = initiateFlow(otherParty)
session.send(relevantTxes)
```

On the receiver's side:

```
session.receive<List<SignedTransaction>>().unwrap { relevantTxes -> relevantTxes }
```

Comment: I want to be able to use subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherSideSession, true, statesToRecord)), But i guess with this suggestion, its more of creating my own custom flow that receive multiple txes and recording them in a loop on the responder side?

Comment: Yes. You'd have to create your own responder flow.